# Prompt Ops Alternatives

Tags: generative-models, llm, sagemaker, mlops, prompt-engineering

What are the main alternatives for prompt ops nowadays? By prompt ops, I mean a comprehensive solution for tracking prompt engineering experiments and also registering prompts in different stages, similar to how I would with an ML model in a model registry.

I went through MLFLow and it seems to have somehow what I look for, instead Sagemaker has tracking prompt experiments features, but it seems to allow prompt registration just using a "fake Estimator" object, that's not a very clean solution. Please correct me if there is another option for SageMaker I did not go through.

Comment: Not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for, but have a look at [prompttools](https://github.com/hegelai/prompttools/) or [agenta](https://github.com/agenta-ai/agenta). You can find more LLM Ops resources in [this github repo](https://github.com/tensorchord/Awesome-LLMOps).

Answer (score 1):

We use Langfuse to manage 100% of our prompts + us them for observability, evals, too.
Excellent product & the team is very responsive to requests and it's open source if you care about that: https://github.com/langfuse/langfuse/